# Убить AsyncTask

Tags: android

Всем привет! Кто знает как убить `AsyncTask`? Вот я нашёл метод `cancel(boolean)`, но когда его используешь то поток не убивается и надо в `doInBackgraund` проверять `isCanceled` `true` или `false` и только потом прерывать процесс. А как сделать так чтобы одним разом убить процесс?

Comment: поток должен внутри себя самостоятельно проверяться и если ему приказали отмениться, то он должен аккуратно завершить свою работу.

Comment: У меня нормально убивается 


 dialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                    appAsync.cancel(false);
                }
            });

Answer (score 1):

Метод **cancel** на вход принимает **boolean**-параметр, который указывает, может ли система прервать выполнение потока. Это просто метка.

То есть, далее в **doInBackground** нужно самостоятельно в коде периодически для проверки вызывать метод **isCancelled**. Как только мы выполним метод **cancel** для **AsyncTask**, **isCancelled** будет возвращать **true**. А это значит, что мы должны самостоятельно корректно завершать метод **doInBackground**.

Т.е. метод **cancel** – это мы ставим метку, что задачу надо отменить. Метод **isCancelled** – мы же сами эту метку читаем и предпринимаем действия, для завершения работы задачи. Именно поэтому "одним разом убить процесс" не получится.

А так же метод **onCancelled** вызывается системой вместо **onPostExecute**, если задача была отменена.